# Iphone Youtube Fullscreen Webapp (standalone) No-audio (BUG ?)

Tags: iphone, web-applications, youtube, youtube-api, iphone-standalone-web-app

.

I embed a Youtube video on a webpage (not a "APP" but a "WEBAPP")
using the standard embed-code as shown below Youtube videos.

When i open my page from a standard Safari-shortcut (homescreen) it all works fine and i do have audio
When i open my page from a custom-icon shortcut (homescreen) it brings up the fullscreen "standalone" (webapp-style) then the video plays ok again but: NO AUDIO !

Since i used the standard embed-code by-the-book
and since it works in standard non-standalone:
This seems like a bug to me. (iPhone or Youtube)

I understand the Youtube API-forum was closed, while they mention i should ask here
so i hope any Youtube-Api-staff (hello...Jarek ?) will reply on suspected bugs.

My 1st post here...hope its a correct posting.

iPhone4s,iOs 6.0.1

.

---/ UPDATE /---

When we LINK to a video (not embed)
then it works in both modes. (standalone or safari)
like that we indeed have audio in both modes.

But it effectively means we cant embed videos for iPhone (and others)
ie: we cant play videos IN/ON the page.

After finding this you may think "not a big disaster since even when we embed it will still
open in the standalone player"...."so you could just as well simply link to it".
But that kills the standalone-mode (webapp) because:

- When we link to open in the same page there is no go back (to previous page) option.
- When we link to open in a new page same-thing...no go back.
- And in both cases the safari browser shows up !
  (which we were exactly avoiding by using the custom-icon to make it act as a webapp).

also as a result our visitor gets lost cause he dont see how to go back to the homepage (site-index)
only way out is to close and load the page again from the iPhone´s homescreen (icons)
or by retyping the url which is to much hassle...hustle ? (sorry not a native english).

In addition when embedding we are forced to use a minimal height of 200 px
(minimal embed without controls-bar, ie: controls set to "0")
for a nice 16:9 embed without large black bars the width then needs to be 356 px,
which is to large to fit on a iPhone in no-resize mode.
it will use to much estate and now cover or partly
hide-below other content and buttons you will have on the (no-scroll) page.

Its a long chain of settings that we need to have (no-resize...etc) to make a mobile-site (webapp)
look nice and work intuitively...changing one causes other unforseen problems.

In addition "playlists", they work in both modes...but they are useless !
i mean if you have 200 videos in a list..how would you expect a visitor
to go to video nr 56 that he likes ?,
that will taker forever !
cause there are no thumbnails (like on a fullsized desktop-page) to go there directly,
so now it`s: play nr1 wait till the (safari/Qt) player-controls show-up
click the next-button...
and do that 55 times until you get to the one you want ?

So anyway you look at it, usefull embedding (or linking) is not possible.
unless this is a bug(s) (that will be solved before iPhone 10 ?)
or if someone knows how to do this better ?

.

.

Comment: That's quite a question. I'll recommend to look through Three20 YouTube player implementation https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Sources/TTYouTubeView.m They have a showcase app that compiles w/o any problem, you could check it first. It has a great embedded videos support, look at `TTCatalog > General > YouTube Player` (master view worked only in the landscape mode for me a few weeks ago, don't be too much confused with it if that's not yet fixed).

Comment: Thanks, but that looks like APP language to me or ? (hope i´m correct)...while i´m talking about a normal webpage (WEBAPP) i thought that was clear...or should i explain that better ? anyway i added(edited) some more "webapp" / "webpage", should be clear enough now.

Comment: I have the same issue in my own webapp in fullscreen so i don't think it is really a YouTube issue. For me it happens only on my iPad 2 but not on my iPad 3, both running iOs 6.0.1

Comment: The 1st problem is that we cant find out if its a bug or not...because youtube-staff does not respond, allthough they closed their own dev-forum and refer us here, obviously moderators here should know if youtube-devs participate in this forum but they give no sign of life either (not doing their job/task), 2nd no-one wants to confirm this on a iPhone(4,5)...so we are not getting anywhere...thanks for your input anyway but it dont bring us any further..wish i would get an exact answer to my exact questions...so i keep saying that this forum is not usefull, not for you and not for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an object instead of an iframe. Had the same problem weirdly enough.

http://www.shockoe.com/blog/embedded-youtube-videos-wont-play-sound-through-speakers-when-played-from-web-apps-added-to-homescreen-fix/

Comment: Thanks but i dont understand how you are using the "old" FLASH-embed-code on phones that cant do flash (iPhone...etc) or is that exactly the misterous thing going on here ? ...i added the [youtube-api] tag to this post...but as expected no sign of life from any youtube-developer who is supposed to monitor posts with that tag...they should jump in to explain what we are doing wrong or if its a bug

Comment: Even with that "youtube-api" tag i get no reply from youtube-devs here,  maybe that is because i added that tag days later after i posted the post,   so i made a new post trying to get their attention but that was closed cause overstressed members/mods closed it cause you cant draw attention to an other post, i could post the post at the start of this thread again but they probably close that again..cause you cant double post,...so i´m stuck in this wonderful forum  no-one helps me to get out of this loop..but when i make one little futile mistake immidiatly 5 jump on it and close my post.

Comment: i dont have enough space to say what i need to say so here´s the last line to above...what to do now ?

Comment: Use litereally the code I posted in the blog. I know it has "flash" in the title but it plays perfectly well on the iphone. Click on the link, read it, and use the code that I wrote there. It works.

Comment: Ok thank you !  ...but i´m not a fan of using un-official workarounds...cause they may break later...so i stil would like to hear from youtube-devs about why and what...but i give up since they refuse to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same bug on ios7 . No sound when play iframe embed code youtube if the page viewed inside webapp